# What does json_encode want as in input?

Tags: php, mysql

From php.net [reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php):

> The value being encoded. Can be any type except a resource.
> This function only works with UTF-8 encoded data.

However, I use the function like this in one case which works fine:

```
$result_array = $this->DatabaseObject->_pdoQuery( 'multiple', 'bookmark_model', array( $this->SessionObject->get( 'id' ) ) );
$result_string =  json_encode( $result_array );
$html_string = "<div id='bookmark_data'>" . $result_string . "</div>";
echo $html_string;
```

But in this case it does not:

```
$result_array = $this->DatabaseObject->_pdoQuery( 'multiple', 'tweet_model' );
// $tweet_object = new MarkTweet();
$result_string = json_encode( $result_array );
$html_string = "<div id='tweet_data'>" . $result_string . "</div>";
echo $html_string;
```

In both cases I'm using PDO library to query the database.  I know I get back what should be essentially an array of arrays...but I don't know if this is resource or not...or how it is structured internally.

There is no major difference between the queries that I can see...here they are though.  Because the two cases are so similar I don't know what is causing the fail.

Here are the queries

```
"bookmark_model" =>         "SELECT * FROM bookmarks WHERE id=? ORDER BY tag, title",

"tweet_model" =>            "SELECT * FROM tweets ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 7",
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What output do you expect? What output do you get?

Comment: this is what blows my mind...I can't get a value count on result_array ( it is 1 when it should be 7 )...it seems to break it before the actual line of execution.

Comment: Is the query executing correctly?

Comment: I have not touched the query code and it works when I put my old custom encoder back in....

Comment: `json_encode` can take anything except a Resource. So your query is probably producing an error.

Comment: Does the PDO library return a resource?  If so why does it work in one case but not the other?

Comment: What does `$result_array` contain?

Post a `var_dump()` of it.

Comment: in both cases...but It works if I decode it using my custom decoder...I mean I can loop through the 2 arrays...where are they?

Comment: Goning to try print_r...just a sec.

Comment: Sorry var_dump gives me object(PDOStatement)#14 (1) { ["queryString"]=> string(47) "SELECT * FROM tweets ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 7" }

Comment: print_r gives me the same type....but there is an array of arrays there...I know the query works.

Comment: It gives you object(PDOStatement) for both queries?

Comment: The only way I can assess what I get is using a foreach...statement

Comment: Foreach with a print_r validates that my query works...and returns what appears to be an array of arrays.

Comment: var_dump or print_r on the object with out using foreach first returns the query type.

Comment: I'm about to hack in a foreach statement to make a "real" array of arrays before passing to json_encode..appears that running it through a foreach converts it.  Don't know why my other query did not need this.

Comment: Temp Fix....       foreach( $result_array as $array_1d )
        {
            $array2d[]=$array_1d; 
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your _pdoQuery() function returns different types in different situations. You may want to check to make sure you got a successful result before trying to encode it.

Comment: I think you are correct but why?  and how can I name these "types"

Comment: I'm about to hack in a foreach statement to make a "real" array of arrays before passing to json_encode..appears that running it through a foreach converts it.  Don't know why my other query did not need this.